# C++: Can you do a lambda implicit copy capture plus explicit copy capture?

Tags: c++, lambda, visual-studio-2015, c++17

Trying to keep an object alive (but not needing to reference the shared_ptr to do so) I found myself writing stuff like this:

```
void ClassDerivedFromSharedFromThis::countdown(ThreadPool &pool, std::string name){
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    pool.then([=, self]{
        for(int i = 0;i < 10;++i){
            atomic_cout() << "Hey [" << name << "]! Our counter is: " << atomicCounter++ << "\n";
        }
    });
}
```

But then got an error in visual studio that said I couldn't copy-capture explicitly because I was already copy-capturing implicitly... This forced me to write:

```
void countdown(ThreadPool &pool, std::string name){
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    pool.then([=]{
        self; //Capture self.
        for(int i = 0;i < 10;++i){
            atomic_cout() << "Hey [" << name << "]! Our counter is: " << atomicCounter++ << "\n";
        }
    });
}
```

I know this works, but it feels wrong. Since I only need the side-effect of the shared_ptr ownership and do not need to reference it directly I would like to express this in the capture list instead of the lambda body.

In my real code I have about 5 or 6 variables I wanted to capture across a couple nested lambdas in network code and implicit capture was way nicer and easier to edit.

My question is: is this standard behaviour or Visual Studio 2015's own take on lambda capture limitations? Do newer versions of the standard allow for this, or has anyone talked about it?

Comment: How about `[this, self]`?

Comment: or `self->atomicCounter++`.

Comment: [this, self] would be fine, except that I had like 3 parameters I wanted to capture too, so it looked like: [this, self, p1, p2, p3] which I actually did at first, but then decided it was a bit grosser than [=]{self;...} @KerrekSB

Comment: I could do self->atomicCounter++, and considered it, but it's not my preference to use a shared_ptr operator -> when I have "this" captured as well.  Though I don't think there's much of a performance hit in using operator-> on shared_ptr, it seems conceptually crufty that there may be *any* cost beyond the copy of the shared_ptr and so I think that's my aversion to it.

I understand there are work arounds and I listed the one I like best (it's subjective though, I understand others may have different preferences.) @Jarod42

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is standard behavior.  From C++14 (N4140) [expr.prim.lambda]/8

> If a *lambda-capture* includes a *capture-default* that is `=`, each *simple-capture* of that *lambda-capture* shall be of the form “*& identifier*”.

So if you have `[=]` then any other capture you do must be done by reference like

```
[=, &some_var]{} // copy all implicitly but explicitly capture some_var by reference
```

The rules do change in C++17 but it is to allow

```
[=, *this]{};
```

Which will capture a copy of the object into the lambda.

Comment: I'll accept your answer shortly, I want to post this question on the isocpp boards for a minute to get some more eyes on it before I do.  Thank you.

Comment: @M2tM No problem.  Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with an [init-capture](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.capture#6):

```
void ClassDerivedFromSharedFromThis::countdown(ThreadPool &pool, std::string name){
    pool.then([=, self=shared_from_this()]{
        for(int i = 0;i < 10;++i){
            atomic_cout() << "Hey [" << name << "]! Our counter is: " << atomicCounter++ << "\n";
        }
    });
}
```

With the bonus that you don't have to declare `self` separately.

Comment: I believe this is only available in C++17, but definitely!

Comment: It's [C++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture), actually.